# My Redux project doesn't render and I don't know where the error is

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

My Redux project uses Redux-Thunk to work with an API, it doesn't render the Header.js element as it was supposed to, I'll show you the files (they are VERY short). I won't waste time showing the store and App.js because I'm sure it is correctly configured. (but if you want I'll share)

Redux > actions:

```
export const FETCH_CHARACTERS_BEGIN = 'FETCH_CHARACTERS_BEGIN';

export const FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS = 'FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS';

export const FETCH_CHARACTERS_FAILURE = 'FETCH_CHARACTERS_FAILURE';

export const actionFetchCharactersBegin = () => ({
    type: FETCH_CHARACTERS_BEGIN,
});

export const actionFetchCharactersSucess = (characters) => ({
    type: FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS,
    payload: characters,
});

export const actionFetchCharactersFailure = (error) => ({
    type: FETCH_CHARACTERS_FAILURE,
    payload: error,
});

const API = 'https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character';

export function fetchCharacters() {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(actionFetchCharactersBegin());
        try {
            const response = await fetch(API);
            const { results } = await response.json();
            dispatch(actionFetchCharactersSucess(results));
            return results;
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch(actionFetchCharactersFailure(error));
        }
    };
};
```

redux > reducers:

```
import {
    FETCH_CHARACTERS_BEGIN,
    FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_CHARACTERS_FAILURE
} from '../actions';

const initialState = {
    characters: [],
    loading: false,
    error: null
}

export default function characterReducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_CHARACTERS_BEGIN:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true,
                error: null
            };
        case FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                characters: [...state.characters, action.payload]
            };
        case FETCH_CHARACTERS_FAILURE:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload,
                characters: []
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

components > Header.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchCharacters } from '../redux/actions';
import './Header.css'

function Header() {

    const characters = useSelector(state => state.characters);
    const loading = useSelector(state => state.loading);
    const error = useSelector(state => state.error);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchCharacters())
    }, [dispatch]);

    if (loading) {
        return <div>Loading...</div>
    };

    if (error) {
        return <div>{error.message}</div>
    };

    return (
        <div className='container-header'>
            <div className='header'>
                <div className='header_logo'>
                    <div className='logo_text'>
                        <h3>Rick And Morty Character's</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <h1>Characters</h1>
                <ul>
                    {characters.map(character => ( 
                        <li key={character.id}>
                            {character.name} ({character.status})
                        </li>    
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Header;
```

can someone help me to find out the problem?

Comment: There's no rerender at all, does the loading state changes ? It seems weird that you are directly fetching state.characters. Do you have only one reducer ?

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

The only issue/discrepancy I see in the code is in the `characterReducer` reducer function in the `FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS` success case. The `fetchCharacters` action returns an array of characters, but the `FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS` case incorrectly nests this result array in the `state.characters` array.

In other words, each time `FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS` runs it nests an array in  an array.

```js
export function fetchCharacters() {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(actionFetchCharactersBegin());
    try {
      const response = await fetch(API);
      const { results } = await response.json();
      dispatch(actionFetchCharactersSucess(results));
      return results;
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(actionFetchCharactersFailure(error));
    }
  };
};
```

[image]

```js
case FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    characters: [
      ...state.characters,
      action.payload // [{ id: 1, name: "Rick Sanchez", …}, ...]
    ]
  };
```

The result is that `state.characters` looks something like `[[{ id: 1, name: "Rick Sanchez", …}, ...]]`.

## Solution

You can either save the payload array directly:

```js
case FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    characters: action.payload,
  };
```

Or if you are actually using the paginated results you can spread the payload:

```js
case FETCH_CHARACTERS_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    characters: [
      ...state.characters,
      ...action.payload
    ]
  };
```

[image: Edit my-redux-project-doesnt-render-and-i-dont-know-where-the-error-is]

[image]